# Как проводить математические действия с данными QTableWidegt в PtQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку число из строки столбца 'Остаток' вычеталось число из столбца 'Пн', потом 'Вт', потом 'среда' и т.д

**main.py**:

```
import sys
#import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from food import Ui_MainWindow


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)

    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

number_rows = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**food.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(849, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 241, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 91, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 30, 211, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 30, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 0, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 821, 451))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(664, 520, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 849, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tableWidget.doItemsLayout)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить ученика"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для малообеспеченой семьи:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для обеспеченой семьи: "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бюджет"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пн"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ср"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Остаток"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "узнать остаток"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не совсем понял зачем вам кнопка, чтобы узнать `остаток` и **что такое у вас остаток**.
Мне кажется что остаток должен рассчитываться **динамический**.

Посмотрите как я заполняю **ячейку** `Остаток`, суммируя данные из ячеек `Пн - Пт`.

```
import sys
#import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from food import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(849, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 241, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 91, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 30, 211, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 30, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 0, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 731, 451))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(664, 520, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 849, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tableWidget.doItemsLayout)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить строку"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для малообеспеченой семьи:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для обеспеченой семьи: "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пн"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ср"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Остаток(бюджет)"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "узнать остаток"))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)

    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        if 0 < column < 6:
            _sum = 0
            for column in range(1, 6):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    _sum +=  int(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(_sum)))

number_rows = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
#import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(849, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 241, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 91, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 30, 211, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 30, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 0, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 821, 451))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(664, 520, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 849, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tableWidget.doItemsLayout)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить ученика"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для малообеспеченой семьи:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для обеспеченой семьи: "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бюджет"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пн"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ср"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Остаток"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "узнать остаток"))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)          # +


    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        print(f"row={row}, column={column}")
        _sum = 0
        if 1 < column < 7:
            for column in range(2, 7):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    _sum +=  int(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())

            _bud = 0
            if self.tableWidget.item(row, 1) != None:
                _bud = int(self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text())
            print(f"_bud={_bud}, _sum={_sum}")

            ost = _bud - _sum            
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ost)))


number_rows = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я исправил надо чтобы из колонки бюджет вычитались числа из Пн-Пт и записывались в остаток

Comment: @finally задавать вопросы в комментариях, плохая практика. Сформируйте новый вопрос, Приложите пример, напишите, что вы пробовали и что не получилось.

Comment: я абсолютно согласен, вопросы в коммах дело такое, но это мелочь, и я чувствую что она решится одним методом от таблицы, вот и не хотел поднимать вопрос

Comment: S.Nick посмотрите мой исправленный вариант сделайте чтобы из колонки бюджет вычитались числа из колонок Пн и т.д. ,а результа записывался в колонку остаток

Comment: @НикитаТимофеев не совсем корректно говорить человеку который вам помогает "сделайте чтобы"

Comment: @НикитаТимофеев  сделал :)